# Why is Caste System there in Hindu religion?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, caste-system

I don't understand why **Caste System** is there Hindu Religion. How could it be possible that a religion divides people? If I am not wrong **Lord Shri Krishna** himself describes caste in **Shrimad Bhagvat Gita**.

Actually, here by asking this I want to know why Lord Shri Krishna describes the caste system, how he could divide his own devotees in terms of:

1. Brahmin
2. Kshatriya
3. Vaishya
4. Shudra

To God all his devotees are same then how could he describes that god will accept prayers and havan only if we do it with brahmins?

Comment: Related : http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/540/why-did-hindus-practice-untouchability , http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/157/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-caste-system-how-has-it-changed

Comment: read my answer here : http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/157/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-caste-system-how-has-it-changed

Comment: even though hinduism is single religion, it's people are not, they divide themselves as brahmin, kshatriya, vaishya, shudra and you cannot deny this fact. we are all different. and still hinduism says that we are one but as per the scriptures we are different, we called this situation "Deadlock" in programming.