# Untouchability during Ramayana or Mahabharata period

Tags: mahabharata, ramayana, untouchability

Are there any references to untouchability or the presence of untouchables during the time of Ramayana or Mahabharata?

Or did the practice start afterwards?

Comment: Related: [Why did Hindus practice untouchability?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/540)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's [a dialogue](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b024.htm) between Bhīṣma and Yudhiṣṭhira from Anuśāsana-parva of Mahābhārata.

> [Bhīṣma says]
>
> I shall in this connection, tell thee what the eternal usage is. **In days of yore**. O king, the Kshatriyas used to serve the Brahmanas. The Vaisya in a similar manner used in those days to worship the royal order, and the Sudra to worship the Vaisya. Even this is what is heard. The Brahmana was like a blazing fire. **Without being able to touch him** or approach his presence, **the Sudra used to serve the Brahmana from a distance**. It was only the Kshatriya and the Vaisya, who could serve the Brahmana by touching his person or approaching his presence.

It looks like untouchability was prevalent *before* the Mahābhārata time; I'm not sure if it was *during* the time.

---

**EDIT**

There are two references to the word [caṇḍāla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandala) in Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇa.

1. Vasiṣṭha's sons [curse](https://www.valmiki.iitk.ac.in/content?language=dv&field_kanda_tid=1&field_sarga_value=58&field_sloka_value=8) Triśaṅku to be reborn as a caṇḍāla because they were upset that he asked them the impossible – he wanted to reach the devaloka (heaven) with his physical body.

   > ऋषिपुत्रास्तु तच्छ्रुत्वा वाक्यं घोराभिसंहितम् ।।1.58.8।। 
   >   शेपु: परमसङ्कृद्धाश्चण्डालत्वं गमिष्यसि ।
   >
   > Having seen his fierce intent, the saint's sons were infuriated. They cursed him saying, "Be a **Chandala**."
2. Sītā [chastises](https://www.valmiki.iitk.ac.in/content?language=dv&field_kanda_tid=3&field_sarga_value=56&field_sloka_value=18) Rāvaṇa saying he cannot touch her the same way a caṇḍāla cannot roam about the sanctum surroundings of a yajña.

   > न शक्या यज्ञमध्यस्था वेदी सृग्भाण्डमण्डिता । 
   >   द्विजातिमन्त्रपूता च चण्डालेनावमर्दितुम् ।।3.56.18।।
   >
   > The sacrificial altar adorned with ladles and vessels and sanctified by the sacred mantras recited by brahmins cannot be defiled by a **chandala** (man of lowest caste).

Now the [Āpastamba Dharmasūtra](http://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/apastamba-dharma-sutra/d/doc116266.html) suggests it's a sin to touch a caṇḍāla:

> 6. Thus after having undergone a long punishment in the next world, a person who has stolen (the gold of a Brāhmaṇa) or killed a (Brāhmaṇa)
>      is born again, in case he was a Brāhmaṇa as a Cāṇḍāla, in case he was
>      a Kṣatriya as a Paulkasa, in case he was a Vaiśya as a Vaiṇa.
> 7. In the same manner other (sinners) who have become outcasts in consequence of their sinful actions are born again, on account of
>      (these) sins, losing their caste, in the wombs (of various
>      animals).
> 8. **As it is sinful to touch a Cāṇḍāla**, (so it is also sinful) to speak to him or to look at him. The penance for these (offences will be
>      declared).
> 9. (The penance) for touching him is to bathe, submerging the whole body; for speaking to him to speak to a Brāhmaṇa; for looking at him
>      to look at the lights (of heaven).

So it's possible that untouchability was prevalent during Rāmāyaṇa time.

Comment: Wasn't Rama cared for by Chandala tribe and called them glorious?