# How this many caste classification occured - different in different states?

Tags: brahman, caste-system, kshatriya

Was this many classification were there in ancient India .I believe there were only 4 classification of  people in Purana.

Brahmin, Kshatriya, Vaishya, Shudra

Why we have this many caste classification and very different caste in every state.

How , Why and when this happened ?

Comment: what you are referring to is *jati*. British mixed both *varna* and *jati* and called it caste (actually derived from a Portuguese word casta) and we still blindly follow what Brits taught us.

Comment: see this answer to know original Varna System http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/8218/3500

Comment: Related [What is the purpose of the caste system? How has it changed?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/157/3500)

Answer (score 1):

It was Risley, the commissioner of the 1901 census of India who introduced so many castes. It was the game-plan of British as part of their divide-and-rule policy:

> “Risley wrote that he wanted his 'scientific' research to 'detach
>   considerable masses of 'non-Aryans' from the general body of Hindus'.
>   He adopted the popular Race Science measurement methods used by French
>   experts, according to which physical traits, such as the size of the
>   nose, were a more reliable measure than skin color. Risley was an
>   enthusiastic champion of the newly fashionable science called
>   anthropometry, which measured various parts of the head to
>   characterize different peoples. He used his measurements of people in
>   India to conclude that there was a remarkable correspondence between
>   two kinds of data, namely, (i) the 'gradations of type' as brought out
>   by certain indices of head measurements, and (ii) the 'gradations of
>   social preference'. This, he wrote, 'enables us to conclude that the
>   community of races, and not, as has frequently been argued, the
>   community of function, is the real determining principle . . . of the
>   caste system'. His 1891 ethnographic study of Bengal became the model
>   for similar studies across India. His program measured Bengali heads
>   and noses with calipers in order to establish hierarchies based on
>   physical body dimensions.” “Based on Risley's research, Indians were
>   classified into seven major races located on a linear scale, with
>   Aryans and Dravidians as the two opposite poles. He also organized
>   'social types' into seven groups. To protect himself, he wrote
>   numerous disclaimers against blatant racism, and against taking things
>   too far. Yet that was precisely what he did and wanted others to do.
>   He claimed that according to his data, 'the correspondence between the
>   two sets of groupings', namely, the seven races and the seven social
>   types, was sufficiently close. He thereby concluded that Indian tribes
>   had turned into castes. He described the various tribal types in the
>   order of their primitiveness, positioning the Dravidians as the
>   lowest, assigning manual labor as their 'birthright', along with human
>   sacrifices to a goddess.16 Those tribes that had developed
>   professional specialization became castes, while those that had
>   remained in a limited geographic territory were still classified as
>   tribes.”
>
> “As the commissioner of the 1901 census of India, Risley wrote the
>   section on caste, which was published in the highly influential
>   Imperial Gazetteer of India, and became the template for academicians
>   and colonial administrators to do their studies. **He decided that
>   Indians consisted of 2,378 main castes and tribes (with sub-castes),
>   and 43 races.** To implement his hierarchy of castes, he decided not
>   to list them in alphabetical order in the census forms, but rather in
>   order of what he considered 'social preference' based on his
>   evaluation of 'native public opinion'. Thus, a hierarchy was
>   constructed and made official. The bewildering array of castes he
>   listed, from which each person was required to choose when filling out
>   official government forms, ran into so many pages that it 'gives so
>   much trouble to the enumerating and testing staff and to the central
>   offices which compile the results.” “Risley translated the dharma of
>   various jatis as 'race sentiments', and made it his ambition to
>   scientifically prove that a comparatively pure 'Aryan type' existed in
>   North India. His obsession with noses caught on with other colonial
>   administrators. For example, noses of Indians became the subject of
>   scientific inquiry for Edgar Thurston, author of the voluminous Castes
>   and Tribes of Southern India (1909). Thurston even used his 'Lovibond
>   Tintometer' (originally an instrument for quality-testing in
>   breweries) to measure the racial features of Indian villagers.”

The above are excerpts from a book 'Breaking India' by Rajiv Malhotra.