# Does caste matter for a person converting to Sanatana Dharma? Will he be fully accepted as a Hindu though he has no caste?

Tags: other-religions, caste-system, conversion

Is it true that if a person converts to Sanatana Dharma, he still cannot be fully accepted as a Hindu because he has no caste? If it is so, then how can such person convince others that he is a sincere devotee of any Hindu God?

Comment: You don't have to convince anyone! Lord Shiva knows you are His Devotee! In fact it is because of His Grace that you're His Devotee :) Let us focus on the Lord and the rest shall be taken care by Him (easier said than done of course!). All the best.

Comment: You don't need to worry about Caste. Varna is important. Varna, literally COLOR, depends only on innate traits and propensities. So, your Guna decides your Varna and Varna is for all 7 billion people on this earth. Shiva doesn't care your Varna, Karma, Jati or anything else which bothers people. You don't need to convince people that you are devotee of Shiva. Just educate them what is true Varna and difference between caste and Varna.

Comment: See these two questions [Converting to Hinduism and Caste](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3452/3500) and [What is the purpose of the caste system? How has it changed?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/157/3500)

Comment: Keshav, you can mark it as duplicate of [Converting to Hinduism and Caste](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3452/3500) rather than closing as personal advice question.

Comment: @Spiritual Seeker, Just a reiteration of things mentioned earlier, there's nothing called caste in Hinduism, you either have *jati* or *varna*. Jati is determined by your genealogy (ancestry), while varna by your propensities (gunas).

Comment: Thank you to all who helped me with the answer. It is great to have a place where I can learn from real people instead of always reading theory

Comment: see see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/24623/13287 and also other related: see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/26326/13287 and see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/26319/13287 and see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/26324/13287 and see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/24722/13287  and see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/26301/13287

Comment: @TheDestroyer How can you split like this when you know well OP is asking about caste/ varna? And if varna was such unnecessary thing why are multiple canonical texts written in great detail about it? Then how will his s adharma based on varna decided? Varna is birth based? How will he do his rituals without varna? Or are you encouraging Spiritual Seeker to remain a panchama?