# How caste is determined?

Tags: caste-system

If I was a person who belong to some other religion and later converted to Hinduism. How my caste would be determined?

In Indian society, I see that the caste is determined based on birth.

Surely, my profession should not play a factor in this because :

- I am not doing business(vaishyas);
- Nor am I a warrior(Kshatriyas)
- I don't teach any vedas (so not Brahmin)
- I have no Idea what Shudra's are responsible for ?

Comment: You might want to read my answer here on how British invented birth based caste and we adopted it, before it was guna-karma based: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/157/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-caste-system-how-has-it-changed?rq=1
Also, each classification can have a lot of things under it in the current scenario, although I am not sure if anyone has done a research on it to create a list.

Comment: Last name based Caste as practiced today is a special feature of Hinduism in India. Outside India it is not a factor and there is no need for a Hindu outside India to have any caste.I doubt if the American actress Julia Roberts cares about caste.

Comment: Shudras are responsible for service to their masters which are from the first three varnas (viz Bramhin, Kshatriya, and Vaishya). There are cases where wise shudras are promoted by their master like Vidura was given post of a Bramhin Minister. How caste is determined is matter of opinion these days.